# How to path data from array as range

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to get some data from the API. I am passing the parameters from the object as 'params'. This object generates dynamically and when the value is the string my request is doing well, but I have an array as key, which is the range of requested values. Thus I need to pass data from an array in this way "Some_data=1000-3500". In which way I can do it?

```
let myParamsObj = {
   data: 'str',
   otherData: 'qwerty',
   half: 4,
   rangeData: [100, 400]
}

axios.get('/api/dasd?', { 
   params: myParamsObj,
   paramsSerializer: params => {
      return this.qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
   }
})
```

I expect the array data to be inserted to the url in this way
    &rangeData=100-400
    &data=str&otherData=qwerty&half=4&rangeData=100-400

Comment: can you add a working code snippet with the current result? then we can modify it

Comment: Do you want to serialize each and every array like this? Or there are  some arrays you need to send in different formats? Do you know which properties should be serialized this way or this rule should  be applied to every "tuple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make your own URL parameters string. Like this:

```js
let myParamsObj = {
   data: 'str',
   otherData: 'qwerty',
   half: 4,
   rangeData: [100, 400]
}

let urlStr = ''

for (const key in myParamsObj) {
  urlStr += '&' + key + '='
  if (!Array.isArray(myParamsObj[key])) {
    urlStr += myParamsObj[key]
  } else {
    urlStr +=  myParamsObj[key][0] + '-' + myParamsObj[key][1]
  }
} 

console.log(urlStr)
```

**UPDATE 1**

---

> I have done it in this way, but I due to the axios docs you can only
>   pass params as the object. That's why I am trying to deal with it

For this, you can do check and modify the `myParamsObj` to see if it has an array and then pass it down. We simply check for `rangeData` property, and if it exists, we modify the property itself, so that when it is stringified by the axios function, it comes out in your desired format. something like this:

```js
let myParamsObj = {
   data: 'str',
   otherData: 'qwerty',
   half: 4,
   rangeData: [100, 400]
}

if (myParamsObj.hasOwnProperty('rangeData')) {
  myParamsObj.rangeData = myParamsObj.rangeData[0] + '-' + myParamsObj.rangeData[1]
}

console.log(myParamsObj)
```

**UPDATE 2**

---

> The point that keys are updated too, and i don't know which key name
>   it would contain. In some way, i need to check if object property is
>   Array and turn it to the string like 100-400

In this case, you can combine both of the solutions above to make it work. Like this:

```js
let myParamsObj = {
   data: 'str',
   otherData: 'qwerty',
   half: 4,
   rangeData: [100, 400]
}

for (const key in myParamsObj) {
  if (Array.isArray(myParamsObj[key])) {
    myParamsObj[key] = myParamsObj[key][0] + '-' + myParamsObj[key][1]
  }
}

console.log(myParamsObj)
```

Comment: I have done it in this way, but I due to the axios docs you can only pass params as the object. That's why I am trying to deal with it

Comment: @SashaZoria i have updated the answer. check now if it helps you

Comment: The point that keys are updated too, and i don't know which key name it would contain. In some way, i need to check if object property is Array and turn it to the string like 100-400

Comment: @SashaZoria i have given another update. hope this one works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which property to serialize this way you could use `filter` option instead and implement whatever logic you need. For example the following code applies custom serialization logic to any array of length 2.

```
axios.get("/api/dasd?", {
  params: myParamsObj,
  paramsSerializer: params => {
    return this.qs.stringify(params, {
      filter: (prefix, value) => {
        const isTuple = Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 2;

        return isTuple ? `${value[0]}-${value[1]}` : value;
      }
    });
  }
});
```